# Manhattan (or city-block) distance

Tags: c, math, distance

[Question can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWShH.png)

If we look at Euclidean and Manhattan distances, these are both just specific instances of p=2 and p=1, respectively.

For p<1 this distance measure is not actually a metric, but it may still be interesting sometimes. For this problem, write a program to compute the p-norm distance between pairs of points, for a given value of p.

```
while(1){

        double x1 = 0,y1 = 0,x2 = 0,y2 = 0, p = 0;
        scanf("%lf", &x1);
        if (x1 == 0.0000000000){
            break;
        }
        scanf("%lf", &y1);
        scanf("%lf", &x2);
        scanf("%lf", &y2);
        scanf("%lf", &p);

        double x_abs = 0, y_abs = 0;

        x_abs = (x1 - x2);
        y_abs = (y1 - y2);

        fabs(x_abs);
        fabs(y_abs);

        double x_calc = 0, y_calc = 0;

        x_calc = pow(x_abs,p);
        y_calc = pow(y_abs,p);

        double result = 0;
        result = x_calc + y_calc;

        double distance = 0;
        distance = pow(result,(1/p));

        if (distance < 0){
            printf("%.10lf\n",(distance*-1));
        }
        else
            printf("%.10lf\n",(distance));
    }
```

Problem is the first testcase is successful but not the second one. Can´t see the problem? Do you?

```
Input look like this:

1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 20.0 20.0 10.0
0

0 indicates end of input
```

Comment: In what way is it not successful?  What answers does it produce?  What answers should it produce? What have you done to identify what is going wrong?

Comment: Cant see the actual test cases, but i know first works since I have both sample input and output for that. With first sample imput, posted above. My code presents: 1.4142135624, 
2.0000000000, 
20.3636957882, which is correct

Comment: I observe that you don't check any of the return values from `scanf()`.  While it should not be a problem with the sample data, you should still do the checking.  It prevents problems from getting out of hand.

Comment: Yes I know, getting warnings doing compilation for that. However, shouldn't be that causing faulty answers.

Comment: `%lf` should rather be `%f` in printf.

Comment: Your idiom of initializing variables to zero immediately before an assignment that sets them to another value is a bit pointless.  Initialize them with the assigned value.  For example, `double result = x_calc + y_calc;`   This is, however, purely stylistic; the compiler will ignore the irrelevant initialization, at least when optimizing the code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala — C99 added `%lf` as a synonym of `%f` for `printf()` et Al for consistency with `scanf()`.  It is not wrong to use either.

Comment: Very true, changed that now! @JonathanLeffler

Comment: The fact you cannot see the test cases indicates you are submitting code to an online judge or similar situation. In that case, you were given a specification for what the program should do. Edit the question to show the complete problem specification.

Comment: Added it @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statements `fabs(x_abs);` and `fabs(y_abs);` do nothing. `fabs` does not and cannot change the value of the expression it is passed. This error results in negative values being passed to `pow` as the first argument, resulting in domain errors and likely NaN returns when `p` is not an integer.

To fix it, change:

```
x_abs = (x1 - x2);
y_abs = (y1 - y2);

fabs(x_abs);
fabs(y_abs);
```

to:

```
x_abs = fabs(x1 - x2);
y_abs = fabs(y1 - y2);
```

Turn on most (`-Wmost` in Clang) or “all” warnings (`-Wall` in GCC or Clang) in your compiler. Both GCC and Clang report this error when `-Wall` is used.